# Composer install: error on temporary file

Tags: windows, composer-php, runtimeexception, temporary-directory

I have a problem with windows 10 and composer (last version).
When I want to execute command "composer install" in my project, a symphony error is thrown:

```
[Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException]
A temporary file could not be opened to write the process output to, verify that your TEMP environment variable is writable
```

My TEMP variable is "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp".
The folder exists and permissions are good.

Can anyone help me to find the problem please?

Thank you.

Comment: This is strange. The temp folder is user-specific and has always full control from its owner - or should have... Please do a double-check on the UAC permissions of the folder. -- You might also run your composer command with `-vvv` to enable verbose output and get closer to the position of the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look into **php.ini** file for location of `sys_temp_dir` and check rights for this folder.

Comment: Thank you.
I change the TEMP folder in php.ini and it's work.

Comment: @Pavel you're my hero

Answer (score 4):

Also in order to clarify your TEMP directory run `echo %TEMP%`. Copy the output directory in terminal and paste it to `sys_temp_dir` in your `php.ini` exactly as it was said above.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows, open Explorer and navigate to that folder.
Try opening it.

When you get a UAC prompt, hit yes to give permission.

Answer (score 1):

I had tried following all answers to no avail.

In my case, this error show up when I opened multiple Powershells and did `php artisan serve` in one of them then in new Powershell I wanted to install a composer package for another project.

**Closing all other Powershells** allow me to continue my work.

This is very basic but I hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem I was using Xampp on Windows 10 and this solution worked for me:
I changed value of `sys_temp_dir` in my `php.ini` to :

```
extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"
```

And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Restarting my computer did the trick.

Comment: Did you just restart, or did you restart after trying one of the suggested solutions?

Comment: The other solutions didn't work for me. I suppose that closing the CLI and deleting the temporary files (prefixed with sf_proc_00) should work as well.