# PHP Composer Temporary File Exception

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm having a problem with composer. When I try to run any composer actions `update` `install` `dump-autoload`, I am getting an exception I can't seem to figure out.

```
[Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException]
A temporary file could not be opened to write the process output to,
verify that your TEMP environment variable is writable
```

I've changed nothing on my server, only some updates, but suddenly I am getting this error.

I'm also not sure how to find which temp folder it is talking about.  I've changed the permissions for every temp folder I can think of. But nothing seems to work.

```
c:\temp
c:\Windows\Temp
c:\Users\%Username%\AppData\Local\Temp
```

So I run `sys_get_temp_dir ();` in php and it says `c:\Windows\Temp` is the temp directory.  Again, I've made sure the permissions are good.

I'm also running the command from Git Bash as administrator.  If that for some reason makes a difference.

I am using

```
PHP vesion 5.4.24
composer latest version
Windows Server 2008 R2
```

Edit: 
**The problem was solved by installing updates for Windows.**
We believe the problem started from another windows update 4 days ago.
I apologize for not having much more information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34741530/composer-install-error-on-temporary-file

Comment: Use `echo %TEMP%` to see what it resolves to for Composer.