# Laravel adds php notices to response content

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have the issue that laravel (version 8) adds php notices I get to the response as html string. This is really annoying because the response should be json and now I have string that contains html and json.
This is how the response looks:

```
<br />\n<b>Notice</b>:  Unknown: file created in the system's temporary directory in <b>Unknown</b>   on line <b>0</b><br />
{\"type\":[\"The type field is required.\"]}
```

Any idea how to disable this behaviour ?

I already tried using phps `error_reporting()` function.
Even with `APP_DEBUG=false` this occurs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Notice: Unknown: file created in the system's temporary directory in Unknown on line 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48192705/notice-unknown-file-created-in-the-systems-temporary-directory-in-unknown-on)

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesnt. My issue isnt that the warning is occuring but that laravel is sending it back with the response content ;-;

Comment: Did you solve it? Im with the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I just hit this too, I fixed it by setting the php `display_errors` runtime config value to `off`.  See https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors

---

More specifically, on my macos/Brew PHP setup it was by editing

`/usr/local/etc/php/8.0/php-fpm.d/www.conf`

and removing the commenting-semicolon on this line

> ;php_flag[display_errors] = off

and restarting the php@8.0 service

> brew services restart php@8.0

On other platforms like Ubuntu, it might be found by grepping under `/etc/php` for `display_errors`